# Merge/Synonymise [right-click-menu] -> [context-menu]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

[context-menu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/context-menu) is the correct term for the menu that appears when right-clicking, however we've also got [right-click-menu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/right-click-menu).

We should merge them together, and synonymise them.

Comment: There's also [tag:right-click] iirc

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - yup, there's also a [few other clicks](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/right-click+or+mouse-click+or+clicking-sound+or+double-click+or+right-click-menu+or+clickonce+or+dwell-clicker) that may need burning as well, but that might require a new question

Comment: I agree on the merge, but the tags are useless anyway.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - Should we merge for now and cleanup later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags have been merged & synonym created